# Are there pros to inheriting a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, graph

I'm new to c++ and I have more of a "design" question than actual code:

I'd like to write a program that works with many different types of graphs, however I want to support any type of vertex or weight (i.e the vertices are strings or char and the weight can be int,double or char or even a class).

For this cause I wrote a class template of graphs, which contains things like a set of vertices and a map with the edges and their weights and get/set functions - Then I have other classes such as finite-state machine graph, a regular weighted graph etc. which inherit from the class template "Graphs". (in each graph I know exactly what types the vertices and weights will be)

I did this as it seemed natural to expand upon a base class and inherit from it. It works so far, but then I thought whats the point? I could simple create in each class one of these generic graphs and use it as I would use an ADT from the STL.

The point being, **is there any benefit to inheriting from a class template instead of just creating a new object of the template in the class** (which itself isn't generic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the explanation you gave above it would be incorrect to inherit the generic graph. Inheritance is a tool to help expand an existing class of the same type to one with **additional** attributes, methods and functionality.

So, if all you're going to do is take the generic graph and make it a specific one by specifying the type of edges and weights without adding anything else to the structure or functionality of the original class then inheritance is unnecessary.

That being said, there are many cases for which one might need to inherit a template class and either keep it a generic one or a specific one depending on the task at hand. For example, if you were given the task of creating a class that represents a list of integers with the regular operations on lists and in addition to implement a function that return (let's say the average of these numbers or any other operation that is not supported by the original generic class List). In this case you inherit Class List and add your method.

Similarly, you could've kept the List as a template class and added the required functionality if that's what the task requires.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering.
I'll explain further: Each graph that inherits the template has several functions unique to it (the way it receives the input, doing a BFS or topological sort etc.). Not all graphs have the same functions, but all of them need some basic functions implemented in Graphs.

Comment: In this case I would suggest inheriting the generic class, specifying the types for the weights and edges and adding your additional functions that are specific for each particular graph. This is what inheritance is for: adding specific functionality for a more concrete type of the original class. Now as for keeping it generic or not that depends on your needs, but based on your initial explanation you should make it specific since each 'special' graph has specific weights and edges.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad and highly depends on your particular situation. Regardless, assuming that your question can be simplified to: *"why should I use inheritance when I can just put the object inside the class?"*, here are two objective reasons:

1. **Empty base optimization**: if your base class `X` is empty *(i.e. `sizeof(X) == 0`)*, then storing it as one of your derived class's fields will waste some memory as the standard forces every field to have its own address. Using inheritance will prevent that. [More information here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)
2. **Exposing `public` methods/fields to the user of the derived class**: if you want to "propagate" **all** your base class's `public` methods/fields to the derived one, inheritance will do that automatically for you. If you use composition, you have to expose them manually.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering.
I'll explain further: Each graph that inherits the template has several functions unique to it (the way it receives the input, doing a BFS or topological sort etc.). Not all graphs have the same functions, but all of them need some basic functions implemented in Graphs.

I think having access to protected fields merits the use of the inheritance in my case, I'd rather not write a get or set for each and every method.